# Performance impact of With statement when referencing object instance variables and properties?

Tags: performance, vbscript, dereference

**Do you guys know how much of an impact a With statement for object instances has when accessing an object instance's attributes and properties? How "expensive" are fully qualified object references?**

Being too lazy to check for myself by benchmarking this, I'd like to ask it here; maybe someone has benchmarked that before.

I am considering stuff like

```
Dim ObjectInstance
Set ObjectInstance=New MyClass

With ObjectInstance
  SomeField=Value
  SomeProperty=Value
End With
```

versus

```
Dim ObjectInstance
Set ObjectInstance=New MyClass

ObjectInstance.SomeField=Value
ObjectInstance.SomeProperty=Value
```

And of course I might have tens or hundreds of assignments. And I might nest With statements if a class references an instance with an instance variable.

Other way of asking:

**Is it correct that using a With statements dereferences the object instance ONCE while the fully qualified reference needs to dereference everything again and again?**

Note we are talking about Visual Basic Scripting Edition, sub-sector Visual Basic Scripting Host, which is a very late-binding (too late-binding? :-) ) interpreter language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did not do exact measurements. However, I can see that hundreds and hundreds of fully qualified assignments take almost no time at all, less than a tenth of a second, on my machine while other stuff takes much, much longer.

**So as long as the property setters involved are rather trivial, I'd never create a `With` statement solely for performance reasons.**

In other words: A counter example are QTPs test objects. Doing a `With` makes sense here more often because each and every reverence of a test object might result in QTP looking up the GUI object in the AUT GUI. Here, `With`'ing might make sense. But this becomes so obvious once you need the `With` because things get real slow then.

So all this is still is an acknowledgement of the rule:

**Don't optimize prematurely.**